# Not able to figure out Logical Error

Tags: java, debugging

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestScoreApp { public static void main(String[] args) {
    // initialize variables and create a Scanner object
    int scoreTotal = 0;
    int scoreCount = 0;
    int testScore = 0;
    String choice = "y";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    // get a series of test scores from the user
    while(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
    {
        System.out.println("How many testscores would you like to enter?");
        int numberOfTestScores = sc.nextInt();

        // display operational messages
        System.out.println("Please enter test scores that range from 0 to 100.");
        System.out.println();  // print a blank line

        for(int i = 0; i == numberOfTestScores; i++)
        {
            // get the input from the user
            System.out.print("Enter score " + numberOfTestScores + ": ");
            testScore = sc.nextInt();

            // accumulate score count and score total
            if (testScore <= 100)
            {
                scoreCount = scoreCount + 1;
                scoreTotal = scoreTotal + testScore;
            }
            else if (testScore > 100)
                System.out.println("Invalid entry, not counted");
            {
            // display the score count, score total, and average score
            double averageScore = scoreTotal / scoreCount;
            String message = "\n" +
                             "Score count:   " + scoreCount + "\n"
                           + "Score total:   " + scoreTotal + "\n"
                           + "Average score: " + averageScore + "\n";
            System.out.println(message);
        }
        System.out.println("Would you like to enter another set of scores? y/n");
        sc.next(choice);
        System.out.println();
        }
    }
}


}
```

The code above is to let a user enter test scores. They first chose how many they would like to enter. A for loop is used to make sure they enter the right amount. After that the number of scores, score total, and average score are outputted. I am current getting the output:

```
    How many testscores would you like to enter?
34
Please enter test scores that range from 0 to 100.

How many testscores would you like to enter?
43
Please enter test scores that range from 0 to 100.

How many testscores would you like to enter?
3
Please enter test scores that range from 0 to 100.

How many testscores would you like to enter?
```

I would appreciate it if someone explains the logical error behind not letting the control of the while loop transition towards the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

You're not getting any test scores because the condition on your `for` loop is wrong.  It's `false` from the beginning, and the loop will only loop if the condition is `true`.  Change

```
for(int i = 0; i == numberOfTestScores; i++)
```

to

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfTestScores; i++)
```